# OpenCV operation with src, dst Mat and memory allocation

Tags: java, opencv

I'm using Java OpenCV JNA wrapper.

I use a lot of OpenCV transformation where I have to provide `src` and `dst` Mats, like for example:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(mat, mat, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 121, 13);
```

As you may see I use the same `mat` instance as `src` and `dst`.

Is it a good practice to use the same instance as `src` and `dst` or it will lead to memory leak issue?

How does it work under the hood? Does it replace the old `mat` memory with the new transformation result or such operation allocates the new memory for `dst` and returns the pointer to it without releasing the memory allocated previously for `src` that leads to the memory leak issue?

Comment: In most cases this is not a problem. As far as I am aware there are a couple exceptions where this might lead to an error message but in general this at least works.
I sadly couldn't find anything in the OpenCV documentations regarding this.

Comment: I faced the memory leak issue with my application and I suspect my wrong usage of OpenCV operations may be a cause of this and this is why I'd like to know how does it work under the hood.

Comment: That is entirely in the realm of possibilities. I never worked with OpenCV under Java sadly, so I can't tell you much more besides that it works for most operations but can create issues. From my knowledge it for example fails for a biliteralBlur filter. It's probably not the cleanest way to go about it, let's keep it at that.

Comment: In `cvtColor` it's not helpful, since you're changing the number of channels, so you will keep reallocating all the time. Since `cv::Mat` (the underlying implementation) does reference counting, leaks shouldn't happen. Usually the documentation mentions whether it works in-place or not -- for example `adaptiveThreshold`: "The function can process the image in-place." Reusing the same `Mat` instance (of constant size and type), especially between iterations, is quite helpful -- you avoid costly allocations, and reduce the rate of address space fragmentation (important on 32bit).